# Better way to convert string to array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a http response from a url :

```
response = Net::HTTP.get(uri) 
=> "[1,2,3,4,5]"
```

response is a string but I would like to convert it to an array like

```
=> [1,2,3,4,5]
```

So I am doing this currently :

```
response = response.split('[').join.split(']').join.split(',').map{|n| n.to_i}
```

I feel this is not the rite way, is there any better way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, it looks like json string. You can use [`JSON#parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) to parse it:

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse "[1,2,3,4,5]"
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JSON.parse(response)`

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use a little bit of regex if you don't want to parse it as json.

```
"[1,2,3,4,5]".scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
```